# STL: apply function to result of adjacent_difference without extra container

Tags: c++, stl

What is the best way to apply some operation (find a min for example) on std::adjacent_difference results without creating extra container?

Edit: manual loop is obvious way but not STL enough.

One way would be to implement output_iterator but looks a bit heavy:

```
template<typename T>
class find_min_oit {
    T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
public:

    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;

    find_min_oit& operator++() {
        return *this;
    }

    find_min_oit& operator++(int) {
        return *this;
    }

    find_min_oit& operator*() {
        return *this;
    }

    find_min_oit& operator=(T const& value){
        if (value < min){
            min = value;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T result() const {
        return min;
    }

};

void find_min(){
    vector<int> arr{1,2,3,6,15};

    auto res = std::adjacent_difference(arr.begin(), arr.end(), find_min_oit<int>());
    std::cout << res.result() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)?

Comment: At this point, a plain old manual loop is probably easier and clearer.

Comment: @Galik The main failing of `<algorithm>` in it's current form is the inability to chain functions together, as the *output* is specified in terms of writing to output iterators. There needs to be a way of specifying "*this* pair of input iterators denote the values assigned to *that* output iterator"

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, I deleted my comment when I realized what I missed about the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`boost::function_output_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) to define the iterator.

```
void find_min(){
    vector<int> arr{1,2,3,6,15};
    int result = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    auto oit = boost::make_function_output_iterator([&result](int value) { result = std::min(value, result); });
    std::adjacent_difference(arr.begin(), arr.end(), oit);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go for a manual loop, unfortunately, the standard algorithms are not made to be combined without a cost... You can look at the [range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library that allows you to combine algorithms in a less-costly way.

```
template <class InputIt>
auto find_adjacent_min_v3(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    auto min = std::numeric_limits<typename InputIt::value_type>::max();
    for (auto it = first++; first < last; ++first, ++it) {
        if (*it - *first < min) {
            min = *it - *first;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

---

For the sake of the exercise, here is a version using the standard [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a custom "accumulator":

```
template <class InputIt>
auto find_adjacent_min(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    auto max = std::numeric_limits<typename InputIt::value_type>::max();
    return std::accumulate(
        std::next(first), last, std::make_pair(*first, max),
        [](auto p, auto x) { 
            auto diff = (x - p.first) < p.second ?
                x - p.first : p.second;
            return std::make_pair(x, diff);
    }).second;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

```
int find_min(){
    vector<int> arr{1,2,3,6,15};

    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    std::adjacent_find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [&](auto a, auto b){
        if ((a - b) < min)
            min = a-b;
        return false;
    });
    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're 80% of the way to answering your own question: just add another template parameter say `typename On_Assignment`, rename `find_min_oit` to something more generic and derived from `On_Assignment` so you can inject data members, then allow `operator=` to be supplied by `On_Assignment`.  You then just need a few lines to write struct with an `operator=` to produce variations in handling of the values `adjacent_difference` will supply.  Alternatively, pass the custom behaviour to the constructor and save it in a `std::function` for use from `operator=`: you can then pass in a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

***If*** it is acceptable that the input data is changed, you might try something like this:

```
std::min_element(x.begin() + 1, std::adjacent_difference(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin());
```

[CPP reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) states explicitly that input and output begins are allowed to be equal.